# JQuery DataTables genérico, error al generar columnas

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Tengo una pantalla la cual quiero convertir en una tabla genérica, es decir, que pueda variar, un modelo que me sirva para múltiples tablas, estoy usando Asp.Net y tengo la siguiente estructura:

Para generar los títulos, desde el controlador le paso un List con todos ellos y en la vista con un foreach lo recorro y los pinta (Funciona).

Para obtener los datos de la tabla uso Ajax en el formato de la [API](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) el cual obtengo correctamente (Funciona).

Para asignar las columnas sigo el formato dentro del ajax:

```
"columns": [
{ "data": "Columna 1" },                
{ "data": "Columna 2" },
{ "data": "Columna 3" },
{ "data": "Columna 4" },            
{ "data": "Columna 5" },        
{ "data": "Columna 6" },        
{ "data": "Columna 7" }
],
```

Este lo genero desde el controlador y se lo paso a la vista en formato string asignado a una variable de la siguiente manera:

```
"columns": data,
```

Me salta el error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined`

**¿Qué puede estar pasando?**